# C# Array Syntax when using object oriented programming

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop, multidimensional-array, ienumerable

I have the following partial classes:

```
public partial class FormInstance
{
    private string referenceField;

    public string Reference
    {
        get { return this.referenceField; }
        set { this.referenceField = value; }
    }
}

public partial class FormField
{
    private string fieldNameField;
    private string fieldValueField;

    public string FieldName
    {
        get { return this.fieldNameField; }
        set { this.fieldNameField = value; }
    }

    public string FieldValue
    {
        get { return this.fieldValueField; }
        set { this.fieldValueField = value; }
    }
}

public partial class EFormData
{
    private FormInstance formInstanceField;
    private FormField[] formDataField;

    public FormInstance EFormInstance
    {
        get { return this.formInstanceField; }
        set { this.formInstanceField = value; }
    }

    public FormField[] FormData
    {
        get { return this.eformDataField; }
        set { this.eformDataField = value; }
    }
}
```

I have a method as follows which has a parameter that is of the above class object type:

```
public int writeEformData(EformData formFields)
{
    object[] results = this.Invoke("writeEformData", new object[] {
                        formFields});
    return ((int)(results[0]));
}
```

In my code I'm trying to initialise the EformData object as follows:

```
EformData eformData = new EformData ();
eformData.EformInstance.Reference = "1234";
eformData.FormData[0].FieldName = "txt_name";
eformData.FormData[0].FieldValue = "John Doe";
eformData.FormData[1].FieldName = "txt_address";
eformData.FormData[1].FieldValue = "10 Acacia Ave";

int result = web.writeEformData(eformData);
```

but when I debug I get error on line 2 `eformData.EformInstance.Reference = "1234";`

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred
>
> Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Whats the correct syntax to initialise the EformData object and assigning values as I'm trying to do above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace

```
eformData.EformInstance.Reference = "1234";
```

with

```
 eformData.EFormInstance = new FormInstance() { Reference = "1234" };
```

..and you will have the same troulbe in the following lines. You have to create a instance of each object before you can set a value to its properties

```
eformData.FormData = new FormField[2];
eformData.FormData[0] = new FormField() { FieldName = "txt_name", FieldValue = "John Doe" };
```